# how to ignore n integers from input

Tags: c++, input

I am trying to read the last integer from an input such as-

```
100 121 13 ... 7 11 81
```

- I'm only interested in the last integer and hence want to ignore all
  previous integers.
- I thought of using `cin.ignore` but that won't work here due to
  unknown integers (100 is of 3 digits, while 13 is of 2 digits & so on)

I can input integer by integer using a loop and do nothing with them. Is there a better way?

Comment: What statement for `cin` have you used to take input? It'd be better if you tell so.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by last integer... Given ```100 121 13 ... 7 11 81``` do you want to output ```81```? Or ```0 1 3 ... 7 1 1```?

Comment: Yes @Roy, Given `100 121 13 ... 7 11 81` I want to use 81 (further).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all depends on the use case that you have.

Reading a none specified number of integers from `std::cin` is not as easy at it may seem. Because, in contrast to reading from a file, you will not have an EOF condition. If you would read from a file stream, then it would be very simple.

```
int value{};
while (fileStream >> value)
    ;
```

If you are using `std::cin` you could try pressing CTRL-D or CTRL-Z or whatever works on your terminal to produce an EOF (End Of File) condition. But usually the approach is to use `std::getline` to read a complete line until the user presses enter, then put this line into a `std::istringstream` and extract from there.

Insofar, one answer given below is not that good.

So, next solution:

```
std::string line{};
std::getline(std::cin, line);
std::istringstream iss{line};
int value{};
while (iss >> value)
    ;
```

You were asking

> Is there a better way?

That also depends a little. If you are just reading some integers, then please go with above approach. If you would have many many values, then you would maybe waste time by unnecessarily converting many substrings to integers and loose time.

Then, it would be better, to first read the complete string, then use `rfind` to find the last space in the string and use `std::stoi` to convert the last substring to an integer.

Caveat: In this case you must be sure (or check with more lines of code) that there are no white space at the end and the last substring is really a number. That is a lot of string/character fiddling, which can most probably avoided.

So, I would recommend the getline-stringstream approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this simple solution for dynamically ignoring rest of the values except the last given in this problem as shown:

```
int count = 0;
int values, lastValue; // lastValue used for future use

std::cout << "Enter your input: ";

while (std::cin >> values) {
    lastValue = values; // must be used, otherwise values = 0 when loop ends
    count++;
}

std::cout << lastValue; // prints
```

**Note:** A character must be required to stop the `while()`, hence it's better put a `.` at last.

#### Output example

```
Enter your input: 3 2 4 5 6 7.
7
```

Comment: Since you're only interested in the last value, there's no need for an array. Just reuse the same variable.

Comment: @john The value's resetting to zero after exiting the while loop (seen in debugging mode) whereas everything's fine within the loop.

Comment: @john I've found a solution for the problem! Just used another variable for that. Removed arrays.

Comment: Good point (about the value being set to zero). That was a change in the C++ standard (C++11 I think). In older versions of C++ that would not have happened. The older way was better I think, and this is a good example why.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for( int i=0; i<nums_to_ignore; i++) {
    int ignored;
    std::cin >> ignored;
}
```